# Modify query with TRUNC, ADD_MONTHS, LAST_DAY from Teradata SQL so as to work on SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, teradata-sql-assistant

I have line of code from Teradata SQL like below:

```
WHERE CAST(COL1 AS DATE) BETWEEN TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -6),'MM') AND LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE,-1))
```

And my question is how to modify above line of code so as to work also in SQL Server?

Comment: Please try, making use of the official documentation, and let us know where you get stuck. This site is not a free coding service.

Comment: I checked it I have somethink like this: cast(dateadd(mm,-6,getdate()) as date) but it gives me 2021-07-18 but I need 2021-07-01, do you understand my question ?

Comment: Please [edit] any clarifications directly into your question. Then I am pretty sure you can find how to get the first of the month in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EOMONTH` to get the last day (DATE) of the current month.
Then use `DATEADD` to add 1 day, which gets the first day of the next month.
Then just subtract months from that.

> ```
> select 
> DATEADD(month, -7, DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE()))) as date1, 
> DATEADD(month, -1, DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE()))) as date2
> ```

| date1 | date2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-07-01 | 2022-01-01 |

Then the equivalent `WHERE` clause is this :

```
WHERE COL1 >= DATEADD(month, -7, DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE())))
  AND COL1  < DATEADD(month, -1, DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE())))
```